# Publish C# WPF application with Webview 2

Tags: c#, dependencies, webview2

I have a C# WPF Application which uses Webview2.

The application works fine on most computers, however on freshly installed windows 10 Pro machines, it does not load as its missing Webview2. (the error is belows:

The application folder contains webview2 dlls. As the application will be distributed I cant require the user to install a dependency. I need the application or setup application to check for and install if required WebView2. How do I add this dependency?

> Application: .exe CoreCLR Version: 7.0.1423.51910 .NET Version: 7.0.14
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception
> has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  --->
> Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.WebView2RuntimeNotFoundException: Couldn't
> find a compatible Webview2 Runtime installation to host WebViews.
> ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at
> Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(String
> browserExecutableFolder, String userDataFolder,
> CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.WebView2.WebView2WebViewManager.TryInitializeWebView2()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.WebView2.WebView2WebViewManager.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf.WpfDispatcher.InvokeAsync(Func`1
> workItem)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf.WpfDispatcher.<>c.<.cctor>b__8_0(Exception
> exception)    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
> target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)    at
> System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args,
> BindingFlags invokeAttr)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args,
> BindingFlags invokeAttr)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
> Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
> at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
> MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object
> obj)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
> msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
> IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
> Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
> at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
> priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
> numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
> Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
> MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
> frame)    at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
> at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
> .App.Main()